# Display Information that matches same data, two tables, match one column

Tags: mariadb

I am trying to create a query that:

Searches two tables, matches purchase order number then displays all the information that has to with that po. From both tables.

Thank you in advance....

Comment: I am trying this:

SELECT parts_po.po, parts_po.part_number, parts_po.description, parts_po.qty, shipping_in.po, shipping_in.project_number, shipping_in.project_name 
FROM parts_po, shipping_in

LEFT JOIN parts.po ON parts_po.po = shipping_in.po

Comment: #Newb at Stackover flow posting... I can not seem to get the code to post as "code"

Comment: indent each line 4 spaces